# Print Button InfoPath Form

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created a Form in InfoPath 2010 and published it to SharePoint 2010 list. The end user needs to print this form and use it for their records. I created a web part that prints the screen, but will not print the page very small and unusable. Is there any HTML coding that I can add to the web part so that the form will fill up the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two things to look into

1. View properties on InfoPath has "Print Settings" tab check to see if the orientation of printing is correct.
2. Try to print form from  Chrome browser if you tested on IE.

Comment: Thanks, a co worker found a work around for me. We send the document to a library and print from there.